Get Color of Active shape layer in Photoshop script
I'm very new at scripting in photoshop and honestly pretty novice at js in general. I apologize if I'm not using the correct terminology.
For very specific and unfortunate reasons, I have to use script to draw a shape layer in the same exact color as the active layer.
I obviously need to get the color of the active layer (by default I think its in RGB but I honestly don't care if its in hex).
I can't figure out what line(s) of code will give me the RGB information in a way that I can put into a variable. It is also not in the not-so-handy PDF adobe has for starting scripting in PS.
Thanks!
This is what I have currently for drawing my shape.
in terms of getting selected layer's color i've tried
activeDocument.activeLayer.color but that kicks out as undefined.
function DrawShape() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var y = arguments.length;
    var i = 0;
    var rename = activeDocument.activeLayer.name;

    
    var lineArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        lineArray[i] = new PathPointInfo;
        lineArray[i].kind = PointKind.CORNERPOINT;
        lineArray[i].anchor = arguments[i];
        lineArray[i].leftDirection = lineArray[i].anchor;
        lineArray[i].rightDirection = lineArray[i].anchor;
    }

    var lineSubPathArray = new SubPathInfo();
    lineSubPathArray.closed = true;
    lineSubPathArray.operation = ShapeOperation.SHAPEADD;
    lineSubPathArray.entireSubPath = lineArray;
    var myPathItem = doc.pathItems.add("myPath", [lineSubPathArray]);
    

    var desc88 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref60 = new ActionReference();
    ref60.putClass(stringIDToTypeID("contentLayer"));
    desc88.putReference(charIDToTypeID("null"), ref60);
    var desc89 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var desc90 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var desc91 = new ActionDescriptor();

//Here is where I'm thinking I could input the variables for R G B
    desc91.putDouble(charIDToTypeID("Rd  "), 255); // R
    desc91.putDouble(charIDToTypeID("Grn "), 0); // G
    desc91.putDouble(charIDToTypeID("Bl  "), 204); // B
//
    var id481 = charIDToTypeID("RGBC");
    desc90.putObject(charIDToTypeID("Clr "), id481, desc91);
    desc89.putObject(charIDToTypeID("Type"), stringIDToTypeID("solidColorLayer"), desc90);
    desc88.putObject(charIDToTypeID("Usng"), stringIDToTypeID("contentLayer"), desc89);
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID("Mk  "), desc88, DialogModes.NO);
    
//Set Opacity, name, and color tag
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer.opacity = 50;
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name = rename;
    
//Delete path
    myPathItem.remove();
};

//grabs current bounds
var LB = activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds;

//draws shape with current bounds. Put the coordinates in clockwise order
DrawShape([LB[0].value, LB[1].value],
          [LB[2].value, LB[1].value],
          [LB[2].value, LB[3].value], 
          [LB[0].value, LB[3].value]);

